# The following packages have unmet dependencies: elementary-tweaks

Tags: package

I tried to install elementary-tweaks to change some of the themes in Elementary OS 6.1.  Method I used must not work for 6.1 or I do not fully understand how to implement it yet.  Now when Install anything I get the following message.

To fix i tried running "sudo apt-get clean && sudo apt-get -f install", but I get the same message when trying to install again.  Anyway to remove this package so I can install again?

Appreciate the help!

ThinkPadT430:~$ sudo apt install
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
You might want to run 'apt --fix-broken install' to correct these.
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
elementary-tweaks : Depends: libgranite5 (>= 0.2.0) but it is not installed
E: Unmet dependencies. Try 'apt --fix-broken install' with no packages (or specify a solution).
ThinkPadT430:~$ sudo apt-get clean && sudo apt-get -f install
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
Correcting dependencies... Done
The following additional packages will be installed:
libgranite5
The following NEW packages will be installed:
libgranite5
0 upgraded, 1 newly installed, 0 to remove and 3 not upgraded.
1 not fully installed or removed.
Need to get 167 kB of archives.
After this operation, 650 kB of additional disk space will be used.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n] y
Get:1 http://mirrors.ubuntu.com/mirrors.txt Mirrorlist [3,335 B]
Get:2 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal/universe amd64 libgranite5 amd64 5.3.0-1 [167 kB]
Fetched 170 kB in 1s (125 kB/s)
(Reading database ... 112490 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to unpack .../libgranite5_5.3.0-1_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking libgranite5:amd64 (5.3.0-1) ...
dpkg: error processing archive /var/cache/apt/archives/libgranite5_5.3.0-1_amd64.deb (--unpack):
trying to overwrite '/usr/share/metainfo/granite.appdata.xml', which is also in package libgranite-common 6.2.0+r2223+pkg122~ubuntu6.1
Errors were encountered while processing:
/var/cache/apt/archives/libgranite5_5.3.0-1_amd64.deb
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
ThinkPadT430:~$ sudo apt install
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
You might want to run 'apt --fix-broken install' to correct these.
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
elementary-tweaks : Depends: libgranite5 (>= 0.2.0) but it is not installed
E: Unmet dependencies. Try 'apt --fix-broken install' with no packages (or specify a solution).

Answer (score 0):

After sharpening my search skills I found the below solved my issue!

sudo apt remove elementary-tweaks

Comment: elementary-tweaks is not compatible with elementary odin. It was made for elementary hera. Try pantheon-tweaks from https://github.com/pantheon-tweaks/pantheon-tweaks

Answer (score 0):

The `sudo apt remove elementary-tweaks` seemd to solve the problem for me too!